# FFMPEG command for video based on ratio

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, exec, watermark

I am using **ffmpeg** (in linux server with php)

and I want to watermark a `png` logo on the `mp4` file, my problem is that

I want to scale my `logo` and change it **based on source video size**(for example 1/4 of height),

I have this code bellow :

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" file-watered.mp4");
```

it works on every video.

### For *Normal* (medium) size image:

[image]

### For *Small* (medium) size image (which is bad!)

[image]

### Ideal output for this size would be:

[image]

I've changed a little bit my first code like this :

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=500:-1[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w):(main_h-overlay_h)" watered.mp4');
```

The main problem is that, I want to change the logo size based on video size.

How can I do it with ffmpeg ?

Comment: @Mulvya thanks but that code gave me no output

Comment: Run the command manually, unscripted, in a command-line interface and provide the resulting complete console output.